# Django can not send email to the recipient

Tags: python, django, email

I have been trying to develop a small demo app which requires to verify email address. After googling I found out that I can use

```
 django.core.mail.EmailMessage
```

to send emails. And below is the changes that I did for my *settings.py* file.

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myaccount@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'MyPass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

I created a message and tried to send in the following way.

```
 email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', ['recipient1@gmail.com', 'recipient2@particulate.me'])
 email.send()
```

But I do not get any email at the recipient end. What is wrong. Help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You should use `django.core.mail.send_mail` instead of the `EmailMessage`. But if you pass the flag `fail_silently=False` to the `email.send()` function you'll see what's going on and why it's failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `from_address` parameter which should go before the list of recipients. I believe the `EmailMessage` constructor should look like this:

```
email = EmailMessage('Subject', 'Body', EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['recipient1@gmail.com', 'recipient2@particulate.me'])
```

It actually looks like you can omit the sender's address, but it will use the value stored in the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` core setting.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `from_email` and you haven't set `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`.
From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects):

```
email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'Body goes here', 'from@example.com',
            ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'], ['bcc@example.com'],
            reply_to=['another@example.com'], headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'})
```

> `from_email`: The sender’s address. Both `fred@example.com` and `Fred <fred@example.com>` forms are legal. If omitted, the `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL` setting is used.